# Alternative to executing Netezza SQL subquery multiple times in Case When?

Tags: sql, performance, netezza

```
SELECT DISTINCT lr.id, 
       lr.dept,
       lr.name
       Case When lr.id IN (SELECT id FROM RESULTS WHERE PANEL_FLAG LIKE '%value1%') AND lr.id IN (SELECT id FROM RESULTS WHERE PANEL_FLAG LIKE '%value2%') Then 1
            Else 0
            End As both_panels,
       Case When lr.id IN (SELECT id FROM RESULTS WHERE PANEL_FLAG LIKE '%value1%') AND lr.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM RESULTS WHERE PANEL_FLAG LIKE '%value2%') Then 1
            Else 0
            End As only_value1_panel,
  FROM RESULTS lr
```

I have simplified this, in reality I actually need many more Case When statements and it's performance nightmare because the subquery executes each time. Is there a more performant way to do this?

I tried creating Common Table Expressions and Temp Tables before the query, but the way I was doing it (replacing the subquery statements with a SELECT from the CTE or the Temp Table) doesn't seem to make any performance difference as it is still executing a query each time.

Answer (score 0):

This would usually be handled with conditional aggregation.  I think this captures your logic:

```
SELECT lr.id, lr.dept, lr.name,
       LEAST(MAX(Case When PANEL_FLAG LIKE '%value1%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
             MAX(Case When PANEL_FLAG LIKE '%value2%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
             ) As both_panels,
       LEAST(MAX(Case When PANEL_FLAG LIKE '%value1%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
             MAX(Case When PANEL_FLAG LIKE '%value2%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
             ) as only_value1_panel,
FROM RESULTS lr
GROUP BY lr.id, lr.dept, lr.name
```

Answer (score 0):

If the sub queries for the ‘in’ lists are with a ‘constant’ whereclause I would consider populating them in a script (commas and all), then inject them into a ‘sql template’ file and run it.
That will run very fast.
Of course the resulting lists should be fairly small (less than 60KB for all lists in total) otherwise the sql statement will become too large.